# SQL Server - Any advantage of using composite primary key here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Below is my table

`Rate` table:

```
rate_id   start_date   end_date     rate1   rate2  rate3
---------------------------------------------------------
  1       2014-08-24   2014-08-28     50     40      30
  4       2014-08-28   2014-08-23     45     36      46
  1       2014-08-29   2014-08-31     60     45      66
```

`rate_id` is a foreign key.

Most of my search queries on this table looks like below

```
select * 
from Rate 
where rate_id = 1 
  and start_date between 'xxx' and 'yyy'
```

Combination of `rate_id` and `start_date` is unique.

1. Can I create a composite primary key on (`rate_id, start_date`)? And is it useful?
2. or do I need to create a nonclustered index on 3 columns?

Comment: For a composite index to be most useful for this query, specify the equality column predicate first (rate_id) followed by the inequality predicate column (start_date).  Note that the choice of the table's primary key and clustered index are independent decisions.  This query will most benefit with a composite clustered index on the columns mentioned because all columns are requested.  You could have different column(s) as the primary key, implemented as a non-clustered index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a composite clustered primary key on those two columns in that order would be very good for that query.

It would allow a simple range seek to be used on a covering index. To be declared as a primary key the columns must both not be nullable and the combination must be unique but I assume this is the case.

The rate1, rate2, rate3 looks suspect though and may indicate your table is not in first normal form.

Comment: Suppose if i want to add one more condition like end_date between 'xxx' and 'yyy' then need non clustered index on 'end_date'?

Answer (score 1):

Choice of your primary key should not depend on your workload.primary key is a tuple which makes a row unique in rowset.

And as far as performance optimization is concerned, it depends on your query workload.IF you are using rate_id & start_date in most of the queries.Then it makes sense to use both columns in index. otherwise you should have only rate_id.

In your case your filter predicate uses both rate_id & start_date in most of the queries so you should have  rate_id+start_date as composite primary key.It will save you index stoarage space and will have less update/insert cost. Because sql will have to update only one index(composite key) instead of 2 indexs.